# Systems of equations involving divergence.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, cauchy-problem

Let $d$ be some given integer, I am considering the following system of equations

\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
    \partial_t v_i(t)=b_i(t,v(t))-\sum_{j=1}^d\partial_{x_j}v_j,\; (t,x)\in[0,T]\times \mathbb R^d\\
    v_i(0,x)=\varphi_i(x),\;\;for\; i=1,...,d.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

which can be written as

\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
    \partial_t v(t)=b(t,v(t))-\sum_{j=1}^d\mathcal I_j\:\partial_{x_j}v,\;(t,x)\in[0,T]\times \mathbb R^d\\
    v(0,x)=\varphi(x)
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

where $\mathcal I_j$ is a matrix in which the $j$-th column is full of $1$s and zeroes elsewhere.
The problem is that this system is not symmetric nor symmetrizable and hence the theory proposed by Friedrichs, Lax, Majda, etc. does not apply.

Are you aware of some way to deal with this kind of equations? Is there a theory for non-symmetric system of PDEs of the first order?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify *your aim*? (Existence/uniqueness proof, qualitative analysis, numerical resolution, etc.)

Comment: So the divergence term on the right, $\operatorname{div} v$,  is the same for all $d$ equations? -- \begin{align}
v_{1,t} &= b_1 - \operatorname{div} v \\
& ... \\
v_{d,t} &= b_d - \operatorname{div} v 
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I tried to delete my answer because it is wrong: See Courant and Hilbert, Methods of Mathematical Physics Vol II, page 140. Your equations have the "same principal part," and are equivalent as shown there to a homogeneous linear differential equation for a function of $2d$ variables ($x_1,\ldots,x_d$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_d$), and to a system of $2d$ ordinary differential equations.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting the answer before, I've been quite busy. This result is very interesting, do you know whether there's some analog result for the case in which there are coefficients multipling each derivative?

Comment: It is the same. Coefficients can depend on $(t,x,v)$.